# Using Quaternion.Slerp() like Transform.RotateAround()

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, interpolation, quaternions

***If my question is confusing, I have provided a VIDEO DEMO.***

I have opted to change a camera rig for rotating around a sphere to use Quaternion.Slerp.  So far, I have been *mostly* successful, but am struggling to achieve a certain rotation.

For y movement, I am using this code:

```
currentRotation = perspective.transform.localRotation;
goalRotation = currentRotation * Quaternion.Euler (controlInput.y * speed.y * 90 * draggable.transform.forward);
perspective.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (currentRotation, goalRotation, Time.deltaTime);
```

As far as I am concerned, the y movement  is correct.  X movement is a little tricky though.  Because it is a camera rig, I wan't to swing around the object, but rotate the object.  So I can't use this code:

```
currentRotation = perspective.transform.localRotation;
goalRotation = currentRotation * Quaternion.Euler(controlInput.x * speed.x * 180 * draggable.transform.up);
perspective.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (currentRotation, goalRotation, Time.deltaTime);
```

Think of it like the main menu of Rocket League except instead of a car, we have a sphere.

[Sketch of the idea.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p32KV.jpg)

In [this video](https://streamable.com/bxp2), I demonstrate the old functionality using RotateAround() and how it compares to my current Slerp() technique.

So my question is really, how can I use Slerp in a manner similar to RotateAround?  I have already tried several cross products of different Vectors but because the cross product isn't constant, this is clearly not how to construct the quaternion.

I am not afraid of complex math, but I don't want to hear "don't use quaternions" as an answer.

Comment: There are few (many to be honest) confusing things in your question. First of all a reader doesn't know whats in your head unless you explain it in your question. You want to rotate something but talking about *movement* in your question. From your video I didn't get the difference between behaviour of two scripts. It would be more easier to understand if you write a bit about it as well. And finally why do you want to use `Slerp` instead of `RotateAround`?

Comment: Rotating around an object is just movement on a track, so I'm not sure why that's a hang up.  If you rotate around an object, your physical position changes.  This is not a question about rotating, but about the use of Slerp.

As for the motivation, it's an issue of mobile performance and the smoothness of movement.  And without question, interpolation is the correct method for smoothness.

The best way I can think to clarify is by saying that I want to rotate an object in the x and y directions without moving the object, but instead moving the camera.

Comment: So if I didn't misunderstand your question, you were using `RotateAround` for camera but now you want to use `Slerp` on the sphere object? and you are storing Camera reference in your `perspective` variable?